# PHP str_replace removes a href value

Tags: php, email, replace, str-replace

I'm using templates to send mail using PHPMailer. Inside this template I have variables %name% and %url%.

The mail I'm sending is a verification mail. The user has to click the button to confirm their account.

Before I send the mail, the aforementioned variables are being replaced using *str_replace()*. Unfortunately, the %url% only gets replaced succesfully once.

Inside template:

```
<a href="%url%" target="_blank">Confirm</a>
...
<p>%url%</p>
```

Inside PHP file:

```
$message = file_get_contents('register.html');
$message = str_replace('%url%', 'nicelinkhere', $message);
```

This results in:

```
<a>Confirm</a>
...
<p>nicelinkhere</p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**New example:**

Inside template (register.html):

```
<a href="%url%" target="_blank">Confirmation</a>
```

Inside PHP file:

```
$message = file_get_contents('register.html');
$message = str_replace('%url%', "www.google.com", $message);
$mail->msgHTML($message);
```

What is in the email:

```
<a href="./#NOP" onclick="return false" rel="noreferrer">Confirmation</a>
```

No clue what's going on here... Maybe server configuration?

Comment: This can't be the real output just from those two commands, because the whole parameters "href" and "target" are missing

Comment: @Skriptotajs that's the weird thing. "href" and "target" get removed from it...

Comment: Then you haven't posted enough information to help you. If you copy these two function calls and test your code, it will work correctly

Comment: @Skriptotajs I added another example. This one is different than the first, but still not working as it should.

Comment: And from where the $mail comes from? What library/framework are you using?

Comment: @Skriptotajs PHPMailer, thus $mail is the PHPMailer instance.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($message);` after the the `str_replace()`?

Comment: @DominiqueLorre <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Confirmation</a>. I guess that it gets weird when it's being send by PHPMailer?

Comment: Yes I suggest updating PHPMailer, perhaps an outdated or corrupted version.

Comment: @DominiqueLorre I installed PHPMailer last week...

Comment: Does it work if you remove the link? It seems to be an issue with href.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123390/discussion-between-blackfayah-and-dominique-lorre).